# Why isn't "DbContext.SaveChanges()" throwing "DbUpdateConcurrencyException"

Tags: entity-framework

I'm experimenting with POCO using `DbContext` and don't understand how to trigger an optimistic concurrency exception. When I call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` at a time when it should fail concurrency, it returns zero instead of throwing `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` or `OptimisticConcurrencyException` for that matter.

It's unclear which should be thrown (presumably the former) but I've read this in detail

- [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 9: Optimistic Concurrency Patterns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/03/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-9-optimistic-concurrency-patterns.aspx)

as well as many articles and can't find anything that addresses the situation. Is there something I need to explicitly do to generate the exception?

Note that my POCO classes and `DBContext` derivative were automatically generated by the "EF 4.x DBContext Generator" and the field being updated has its "Concurrency Mode" set to "Fixed" (though I don't think this has any impact in the POCO environment).

Answer (score 3):

If you create two instances of your context in different threads, or inside one another, then  you can get a DbUpdateConcurrencyException. I.e.

```
using (var db = new myContext())
{
    db.PocoClass.Add(someNewOrUpdatedObj);

    using (var db2 = new myContext())
    {
        db2.PocoClass.Add(someNewOrUpdatedObj);
        db2.SaveChanges();
    }

    db.SaveChanges(); //DbUpdateConcurrencyException thrown here
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. In my own experiments however, if I retrieve and update a field, break at "SaveChanges" and then update the same field outside of my app (using other means), and then allow "SaveChanges()" to proceed, it doesn't thrown any exception. It just returns zero (no "DbUpdateConucrrencyException"). If I run the same experiment using an "ObjectContext" however (instead of "DbCOntext" - no POCO IOW), it works as expected ("OptimisticConcurrencyException" is thrown). Any ideas?

Comment: I just tested your own scenario and the same problem occurs as I expected. First call to "SaveChanges()" works, second call returns zero (no exception).

Comment: Just an update that I've since discovered the "ConcurrencyCheckAttribute" (not widely advertised) but it doesn't seem to be working as advertised. Will post back once I figure things out.

Comment: V. interesting. Will have to test myself later